# Solution to sde with specfic mean

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

**Goal:** 
I'm attempting to work backwards to recover an SDE as follows:

**Example:**
$e^{\mu t}$ is the mean of the geometric Brownian Motion, which solves the SDE: 
\begin{equation}
dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma dW_t \mbox{; } (t \in (0,\infty)).  
\end{equation}

**Question:** 
What SDE has a solution which has mean $t^ke^{\mu t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
dS_t = \Big(\mu + \frac{1}{t}\Big) S_t\,dt + \sigma dW_t
$$
for example.  Of course this comes with a restriction to $t > 0$.

Comment: I modified the question to allow for higher powers of $t$, in that case would:
$$
dS_t = \Big(\mu + \frac{1}{t^k}\Big) S_t\,dt + \sigma dW_t
$$, work then?

Comment: In the more general form you've added, you could get a stochastic process with the desired mean by considering $$dS_t = \Big(\mu + \frac{k}{t}\Big)\,S_t\,dt + \sigma \, dW_t$$.

Comment: More generally the process $$dS_t = \Big(\mu + \frac{a}{t^{1-k}}\Big)\,S_t\,dt + \sigma \, dW_t$$ would have a mean $$\exp\Big(a\,\frac{t^{1-k}}{1-k} + \mu t\Big)\,S_0\,.$$

Comment: Perfect, thanks Josh! :)